# How to fix windef.h and windows.h errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, mingw32

I've been using windows.h header files for a long time, but recently there is an error when I include windows.h or windef.h header files.

this is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
system("start opera");
return 0;
}
```

that is a small peace of the error output:

```
c:\mingw\include\windef.h:315:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type 
conversion before '(' token
DECLARE_HANDLE(HWND);
           ^
c:\mingw\include\windef.h:316:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type 
conversion before '(' token
 DECLARE_HANDLE(HWINSTA);
           ^
c:\mingw\include\windef.h:317:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type 
conversion before '(' token
 DECLARE_HANDLE(HKL);
           ^
c:\mingw\include\windef.h:319:9: error: 'HICON' does not name a type
 typedef HICON HCURSOR;
         ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\windef.h:325:2: error: 'LONG' does not name a type
  LONG left;
  ^~~~
c:\mingw\include\windef.h:347:2: error: 'SHORT' does not name a type
  SHORT x;
  ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\windef.h:348:2: error: 'SHORT' does not name a type
  SHORT y;
  ^~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windef.h:42:0,
             from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:42,
             from general.h:9,
             from main.cpp:17:
c:\mingw\includ
```

Comment: Please also add to the question, what is declared up to and including the windows headers (in main and general). Did you try including them first?

Comment: Is this the first error? Are there any warnings about redeclaring any macros beforehand?

Comment: @Mestkon that a just a small piece of the error, you can find the whole piece here -> https://docs.google.com/document/d/18-uTY875O8t6DUBB_s0nBVZL66ahosmAstFvwFlfBe0/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk yes, I edit the question and now i included an example that produces the same error.

Comment: Your example is not the same as the error. Does this example code generate the same error for you? In the error code "general" includes windows. Please show how YOUR includes are copied. Not example code -  but reproduction code

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk that exxample code produces this exact error message

Comment: Please compile that example code, and provide the full compiler output from that.

Comment: Possibly your MinGW is broken. As MinGW-w64 is a more up to date alternative you should maybe try that. You can get a standalone build from https://winlibs.com/ that you can try without removing your current MinGW.